# How to convert div into pdf which include table and d3 graphs in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas

I want to convert my div into pdf which includes table and d3 graphs
till now I have used `html2canvas` and  `jsPdf` which showing pdf in incorrect shape.
Is there any way I can do it.

````js
const pdf = new jsPdf();
        html2canvas(this.canvas, {
            scale: 0.5,
            scrollY: -window.scrollY,
            width: 1500
        }).then(result => {
            let imgData = result.toDataURL('image/png', 0.9);
            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
            pdf.save('download.pdf');
        })```
````

Comment: Usually those pdf rendering runtimes only work well with basic html. Have you looked into a *backend* pdf library? You could for example (without such library) save your canvas as an image then upload to the backend for further use in a pdf file (with a pdf library).

Comment: but still the problem in capturing the image right and I want to do in front end